# How to search for employees?

Tags: support, search, moderators

Moderators tab doesn't show it (it shows only appointed or elected mods). How can I search for employees (that have accounts anywhere on SE)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are listed on the Stack Exchange about page:

https://stackexchange.com/about/team

You can see the account of the employees (who have an account) by clicking on their picture on the about page.

Comment: but far not all of them have accounts, thats not interesting :(

Comment: @nicael For an employee who has an account, click on their picture and you'll see their account.

Comment: btw funny gifs :)

Comment: :( Link has changed, so this no longer answers the question.