# Accounts got merged accidentally or automatically

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

My brother and I had two different accounts. I don't know what happened, but while asking a question on SO, our accounts got merged. Now I'm not able to see my account and profile; it's showing all the details of my brother if I login with my account.

How can I split it into two different accounts?

Comment: I don't think there's anything more you can do than what you have all ready done, I believe that only the mods can reverse this (or perhaps only the paid SO staff can - no idea what they are called). So I think it's all about waiting for them to notice this.

Comment: @Epodax They are [employees](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275527/how-to-search-for-employees)

Comment: I expect that the same computer, logged in with the same windows account has been used to access both stackoverflow account.    Therefore cookees as well as IP address where the same.

Comment: Yes exactly this was the scenario ...

Comment: I would argue that this is actually a security vulnerability as it can leak someones identity. For example, a separate account is created to be a whistleblower about their company doing something bad. Then poof, all of the sudden the accounts get merged and the post is suddenly the persons real known work identity.

Comment: Here's another scenario: My employee is helping people use our software. But using another identity they start talking about Trump. Then poof, all of the sudden the accounts get merged and people associate my company with having strong political opinions.

Answer (score 60):

This *seems* to have been done automatically; the merge has been attributed to the "[Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=profile)" background process, rather than a specific staff member (moderators cannot do user merges, nor can we undo them).

Your best bet is to contact the community team via https://stackoverflow.com/contact, explain the situation to them, and ask them to revert the merge.

Comment: Automatic profile merges... what could possibly go wrong?!

Comment: Probably auto merged based on your ip use, people  do often share ips, corporate proxies, university buildings?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dunno, it could get rid of my [redundant alias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "Nice Post-It!" Badget needed: Comment with 5x more upvotes than votes on the post it is attached to, and at least 20 votes on the post it is attached to.

Comment: @Yakk: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279255/155739

Comment: As you suggested I have sent a mail yesterday, haven't got any reply yet...