# Merged accounts, wrong email keeps being used

Tags: support, email, subscriptions

I had 2 account merged, one using old email @foocompany, one using new email @gmail.

I deleted all mention of old @foocompany email from my profile settings that I could find. Still, when I subscribe to tags, Stack Overflow keeps using the old @foocompany email address.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I change my gravatar-linked email?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360018/7586)

Comment: Possibly same as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322755/accounts-got-merged-accidentally-or-automatically

Comment: If you go to your profile Edit Profile & Settings->Edit Email Settings and check the very first email there. Also, there's "Question Subscriptions" which takes you to another page listing tags you're subscribed to - you can then click "manage" there and it'll show what the email address is for that. If that's not the one you're after, you should be able to click "edit" and change that to one you've validated...

Comment: The very first (and only) email in those settings is my gmail address. I deleted the other one after merging. Still. When I subscribe, I get a message about the confirmation mail going to the old address @foocompany.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from myself on [another question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360038) (I *just* posted this):

> See back when we pushed out the new Email Settings section of the profile and updated all of our mailing habits, part of the process was to obsolete the usual Email field in the main Edit Profile screen (you know, that "Private Information" section). That field still exists in the database - it has to until we actually change everything to stop using it. It just can't be edited anymore. That means whatever email you had there before the big email changes went live is now stuck there until the field is gone for good.
>
> Development teams are still working to make sure the field isn't used anymore, and we've been keeping a list of various places where we find out it is.

Your old email is being pulled incorrectly from that old, obsolete field. We'll make sure that tag subscriptions are on the list to be fixed to use the new email settings.