# How do I change my gravatar-linked email?

Tags: support, email, gravatar

A few months ago I've changed my email in Stack Overflow from `my@email.com` to `my+tagged@email.com` in order to change my gravatar icon on Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to change it back but can't seem to find this setting... Was the per-site email setting removed?
The email I have in *Edit Email Settings* has my correct email, and I didn't find another setting.

Comment: Alternative title: "Help! I'm stuck as a fox!"

Comment: If you're using Firefox, it might be protecting your gravatar intentionally. Try doing the same from Chrome.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - I am using Firefox. What do you mean? There used to be a textbox I could edit, I doubt Firefox would hide that.

Comment: I was just kidding.. the fox.. you know.

Comment: Oh... right. Totally got it. Yes. I was also kidding. 

Comment: Downvoter - Can you please post a free-hand circled screenshot of the appropriate setting? I know it's there, but I can't find it.

Comment: … can’t you just log in to Gravatar and change the image there…?

Comment: @poke - That'd work. I have multiple emails in the same Gravatar account, each with its own icon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, it's, uhhh, not possible.

See back when we pushed out the new Email Settings section of the profile and updated all of our mailing habits, part of the process was to obsolete the usual Email field in the main Edit Profile screen (you know, that "Private Information" section). That field still exists in the database - it has to until we actually change everything to stop using it. It just can't be edited anymore. That means whatever email you had there before the big email changes went live is now stuck there until the field is gone for good.

Development teams are still working to make sure the field isn't used anymore, and we've been keeping a list of various places where we find out it is. They're aware that Gravatar still uses it, but I'm not sure what the status is on a fix.

Comment: I knew it! So, I guess...`update users set email = 'kobikobi [ב] gmail.com'  where id = 7586`? Actually, I don't mind keeping the fox for a while longer. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still the case or outdated?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use your gravatar image as the profile image on Stack Overflow. You can upload your own image as a profile picture, by editing your profile (under Stack Overflow -> user profile -> edit profile & settings):

[image]

Comment: What if I do want to use Gravatar? I'm old school. Still, +1 for posting a reasonable solution (although I did see it before).