# How can I change my email address on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, email

I've tried several times to do this, but each time have failed.

I've got an old Yahoo email associated with my Stack Overflow account that I'm trying to deprecate.

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to update my email on Stack Overflow.

Some talk abounds of how it is 'structurally impossible' due to 'baked in design'.

Others say you have to open up a new account then do some sort of transfer. I did just try this route, but it failed. It is probably not happy with me trying to use the same username. If I have to have a new username then that is just crazy. That would mean you would have to become a different person on Stack Overflow every time your email address changes?

Why can't Stack Overflow be like every other web-based service I use and provide the option to change your email address?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I change my gravatar-linked email?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360018/7586)

Comment: hmm - ok, But I log on with email address and pwd, I want to use the same email across all my services ideally. I also get email alerts from SO, i.e. when someones left an answer for me. I don't want those to go to an old deprecated email account. Is it just old school to be using SO with email? - is there some other (better ) workflow that I don't know about or is the UX just broken in this area?

Comment: Strange you ask this...Over the weekend I ran into some issues with my email (someone had hacked my account and gained access to my email).  I got a new email address and it took me a whole 10 seconds to update it on stackoverflow.  I just went to the profile page and there was a setting for Editing Email information.

Comment: @JonH  you got some good SO skills there

Comment: profile->Edit Profile and Settings->Edit Email Settings->Email Address seems really easy. Where did you look for the settings?

Comment: Seriously, if you can point to anything specific that stopped you from locating these settings, the Stack Overflow UX people would probably like to know. Were you unable to locate your profile page? Was one of the steps in the link chain I mentioned missing?

Comment: like many things in life - now its been pointed out it seems very simple, but for all the tea in china I couldn't find it before (and I did make several attempts). There are quite a few SO answers that suggest you can't do it, so I think that made me believe it was harder than it actually was?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

#### Do *BOTH* #1 and #2 to deprecate your old email address

1. **Add the new email address as a login:**
   You can register new logins here:
   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current
   Click the "Add more logins…" button just above the page footer. You will need to enter the new email and password. An email will be sent to you and you'll need to click on the button provided in the email to confirm that you control the email address.
2. **Change where Stack Exchange sends email notifications:**
   You can change the email address to which Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange sends you email here:
   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current
   If you do this step first, you will have to go through email address verification at that time.
3. **If you want, remove the old email address as a login (after verifying the new one works):**
   You can *remove* your old login here (same as #1):
   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current
   It's recommended that you verify that you can log in using your new email address prior to removing the old email address as a login.

If you perform steps #1 and #2, then you will be able to log in using your new email address and Stack Exchange will send email to your new email address. If you perform step #3, then you will no longer be able to use your old email address to log in.

Comment: ok that seems like it may have worked. I added my new email. I'd already created a new account with that email and a new pwd. Logging in with the new email/pwd combo and my original account details show up, i.e. it seems to be linked to my orginal username. I'd still argue that its far from intuitive

Comment: have also managed to remove the old email now - so all good i think..

Comment: unfortunately there are a lot of wrong answers out there on how to do this which can send you off piste..

Comment: This doesn't change the email address for *subscriptions* thouogh. I just found that out. I have changed my email address in the sessings long ago. It was showing correctly, but I was still getting notifications about new questions to the old address. It was driving me nuts. Now I found that under "subscriptions" on the network profile, I have to change the email address for each subscription individually. Wow, that's odd. And confusing. Why is it this way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, those login settings are network-wide, unlike the other settings (?). 
One question though: I see a login in that list that just says "Stack Exchange", without an e-mail address. What is this? It has a password attached to it, as it has a "Change password" button next to it.

Comment: When I try that first link and click save, it just resets the page and puts my email address back to what it was.