# How do I enable Gravatar instead of Identicon?

Tags: support, email, gravatar, avatar

I haven't used *Gravatar* with my email when I signed up some years ago.
I haven't used *Gravatar* with my new email when I changed it a while back.

Now I've enabled *Gravatar* to be used with the email I use on *Stack Overflow*, but I never got the option to change my avatar to my *Gravatar*. I changed to an uploaded image and could only revert back to the *Identicon*.

Is this because my old email is still being used to get the *Gravatar*?
Is this because I wasn't using *Gravatar* and the hash therefore get salted and doesn't notice the change?

In [How do I change my gravatar-linked email?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360018/how-do-i-change-my-gravatar-linked-email) I learned that there was an issue to change the *Gravatar* email address.

Comment: Damn, I had no idea there was an old database field that is used for the gravatar image. I'd say the gravatar option is essentially dead now, only still there to support legacy accounts. Since mine works, I ain't gonna touch it.

Comment: Your account currently has no gravatar option set, and I don't think you can add it back, so only the identicon and uploaded image options remain.

Comment: Is there any way to change this option, somehow? Or was support for _Gravatar_ fully dropped and just lingers around?

Comment: It looks to me (as an outsider to the company, but with moderator access so I can see quite a lot of stuff on other accounts), that the Gravatar option has been deprecated. *Existing accounts* get to keep their gravatar currently set (I have one set), but no one without a gravatar set can switch to one. I have no official confirmation of this, I have no first-hand knowledge of this.