# Subscribing to a tag sends the confirmation email to a wrong email address

Tags: support, email, subscriptions

I have attempted to subscribe to tags on both Stack Overflow and Meta today using the hover display.

[image: Tag dropdown with subscribe link]

When clicking *subscribe* the confirmation email is going to a **.edu** email address that I have never owned instead of my configured email the ends on **.com**. The rest of the email address is the same besides the [TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain). I may have signed up using a **.edu** address a few years ago, but now I sign in using Google.

This looks very similar to *[Merged accounts, wrong email keeps being used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360012/merged-accounts-wrong-email-keeps-being-used)* - I can edit the per subscription email settings after subscribing, but new tags still go to the incorrect email address.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? I have encountered a slightly different problem. I cannot receive the confirmation email after subscription to some tags.