# Why did I lose two rep for unaccept on a question I didn't ask?

Tags: support, specific-question, reputation

Five hours ago I lost two rep for *unaccept* on a question I haven't visited in quite some time. I can't figure out why this was applied and why now. Some relatively long time ago I upvoted the linked answer, one other answer, and the question.

> -2    5 hours ago     unaccept    [What does the leading semicolon in JavaScript libraries do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873983/what-does-the-leading-semicolon-in-javascript-libraries-do/36672779#36672779)

Comment: Interesting.  You're not even the question author, so...it's not like unaccepting the answer should affect you at all.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The single accepted answer to a [question you posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672744/why-start-a-script-with-a-semi-colon) (deleted, 10k+ only) was merged into that post, and in the process that answer was un-accepted.

You can see that it was merged in the [answer timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36672779/timeline):

> 5 hours ago
>   history
>   post merged (destination)

and you yourself can see the -10 for the question deletion in your reputation history; following the link from there to the question, you can see it has a 'merged' banner on it.

Comment: Wait, what. Merging *actually happens*!

Comment: @Raedwald [All sorts of things get merged here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322755/accounts-got-merged-accidentally-or-automatically/322761#comment342792_322761)